# Virtual Box; networking individual VMs when one is a Domain

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dns

I am trying to mimic a clients environment.

Ultimately my goal is to install and play and test Redmine.

Currently there's is installed on a Windows 2012 server R2.  that server is attached to a Domain Controller also running Server 2012 r2.

So I have created two VMs both running Server 2012 R2.  I have instructed one to act as a DC and named the DC and domain Redmine.The 2nd server is OS only so far (it will be SQL and Redmine soon enough).

I am trying to join the second server to the domain i created on the 1st server 
redmine".  I have attempted numerous different combinations of the network controllers.  All I read seems to say Bridged is the way to go, but when I try to hit the DC from Server 2, it times out saying it cant see it basically.  I feel like each machine is on its own internal DHCP driven network.

How do I get them on the same network and able to join server 2 to server 1's DC?  And yes I know that typically it would require changing the DNS addresses on Server 2 so that they point at Server 1, but that does not work. I can not ping them to each other either.

I am looking for the optimal network configuration to accomplish this.  The OS are not up to me, and running Redmine in windows is not up to me either.  They are simply the limits i find myself constrained too.

Please dont send me to documents on How to set up a basic non-VM network.  I have worked in the industry for many years and can do this in real HW/SW with my eyes closed.  My problem is specific to the VM's, how do Iget them on the same network so I can promote etc.?

Answer (score 0):

As long as both VM's are set to the same type of networking (bridged, NAT, whatever), they should have no trouble seeing each other.  The nice thing about bridged is that you can treat them exactly the same way you would treat physical machines.  Since these are servers, I assume you gave both of them static IP addresses?  What happens when you try to ping one VM from the other?  Also, make sure the MAC addresses are different (if you cloned one machine to get the second one, you need to make sure you generate a new MAC address).